# Tensorflow: How to Manually Edit Gradient Values

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I am reading gradient values from a outside source (i.e computation is done elsewhere, but I want to accumulate the different sources in a "master" network), and I would like to just use the `apply_gradients()` op in tensorflow. The problem is, the gradients get sent in as floats. Is there any way I can use the float array to apply the gradients with the built-in `Optimizer` functions?

In a very minimal example / test case, this is what I would essentially like to do.

```
W = tf.Variable(1.0)
b = tf.Variable(2.0)

trainable_variables = [W, b]

gradients = [0.05, 0.01] # Example gradients for W, b

# ... Somehow make this gradient vector into a tensor

optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_tensor, trainable_variables))
```

Comment: your question isn't clear, add more information and sample codes.

Comment: Good point, added a very minimal example case of what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you tried [tf.convert_to_tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing so, in particular, you can just create **placeholders** for your external gradients, and combine them by simply performing arithmetics on them before apply_gradients.

```
x = tf.Variable( ... )
f = x ** 2
g = tf.gradients(f, x)
my_gradient['x'] = tf.placeholder( ... ) # same size and type as x

g = [(grad + my_gradient[var.name], var) for grad, var in g]

optimizer.apply_gradients(g)
```

and now during optimisation step, just feed_dict my_gradient['x'] value to the computed one.

If they do not change overtime, you could use tf.constant() instead but I can't see any mathematical situation to have a constant (and non-zero) gradient in ML.